# Pagination algorithms for HTML

Tags: c#, html, pagination, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am building an ebook manager app for the Windows store using Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 preview. I have a new webview control that is able to resolve uri's and load the HTML and CSS.
However there is a lot of data in one HTML file and I would like to paginate it someway. My Questions are:

Is there a way to do this with the stream in C#?

Are there any examples out there on paginating HTML content?

Is there a way to measure programmatically how much screen real estate will be used by a particular piece of HTML?

Comment: If you convert the HTML to RichText, then you can use RichTextOverflows to automatically put overflowed content into new columns, similar to the Bing News app.

Comment: I thought about that approach but that seems overkill as the Webview control is already heavily optimized for loading and parsing HTML. Plus that would really diminish the usefulness of the EPUB standard.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on the type of data that is send back to the browser, also how you want to present it afterwards.

Perhaps you can show some sample data which you want to paginate

Comment: It is static HTML that resides in the epub file. No browser is involved. An epub is a digital representation of a book. I can easily open each content file which is an HTML page and display it to the user. But that provides no sense of structure for the book.